# CTest CDash: SubProject xml elements missing under Sites using include(CTest) only to submit test results

Tags: properties, label, ctest, subproject, cdash

I built a source tree with several independent projects using CMake to build each individual project.

Important: I do NOT have a global CMakeLists.txt file to perform the whole build, I use generic scripts (windows (.cmd) and unix (.sh)) to loop on all subprojects. I want to keep projects **independent** and yet have the ability to build them all automatically.

In CDash on the other hand, I'd like to see all these independent projects as *CDash subprojects* as part of a bigger unique artificial *CDash project*.

To work with CDash, I followed the method described at:
http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Testing_With_CTest

I'll name this **method A**.

Namely, I do:

```
enable_testing()
include(CTest)
```

And, then put some tests of my own.

Afterwards, I tried to follow following page indications to make my individual projects seen as subprojects:
http://www.kitware.com/media/html/CDashSubprojects.html

I'll name this **method B**.

**The problem** is that the *xml* that are submited to CDash lack the `SubProject` and `Labels` xml elements (tags for xml abusers), those under `Sites`, although my CMakeLists.txt (actually my CTestConfig.cmake) file has the following global property settings (I tried to put it in both files):

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY SubProject ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY Label ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

where CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME is -of course- well defined.

- **Do you know wjy `SubProject` and `Labels` elements are missing under `Sites` element of submited xml files?**
- **Can methods A and B be mixed?**

Furthermore, I checked CTest source, these global properties are added by this function (I took it from 2.8.10, couldn't download the source of 2.8.11 I'm using, so I hope there's no change it that otherwise sorry):

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void cmCTest::AddSiteProperties(std::ostream& ostr)
{
  cmCTestScriptHandler* ch =
    static_cast<cmCTestScriptHandler*>(this->GetHandler("script"));
  cmake* cm =  ch->GetCMake();
  // if no CMake then this is the old style script and props like
  // this will not work anyway.
  if(!cm)
  {
    return;
  }
  // This code should go when cdash is changed to use labels only
  const char* subproject = cm->GetProperty("SubProject", cmProperty::GLOBAL);
  if(subproject)
  {
    ostr << "<Subproject name=\"" << subproject << "\">\n";
    const char* labels =
      ch->GetCMake()->GetProperty("SubProjectLabels", cmProperty::GLOBAL);
    if(labels)
    {
      ostr << "  <Labels>\n";
      std::string l = labels;
      std::vector<std::string> args;
      cmSystemTools::ExpandListArgument(l, args);
      for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = args.begin();
          i != args.end(); ++i)
      {
        ostr << "    <Label>" << i->c_str() << "</Label>\n";
      }
      ostr << "  </Labels>\n";
    }
    ostr << "</Subproject>\n";
  }

  // This code should stay when cdash only does label based sub-projects
  const char* label = cm->GetProperty("Label", cmProperty::GLOBAL);
  if(label)
  {
    ostr << "<Labels>\n";
    ostr << "  <Label>" << label << "</Label>\n";
    ostr << "</Labels>\n";
  }
}
```

- **Does `ch->GetCMake()` return NULL somehow in my case?**

Thanks in advance for your help. Regards.

---

P.-S.: Please refrain yourself from asking me why I do this or that (unless you have a relevante point to make), because -one- it doesn't help, -two- if I do it, it's because I've got a good reason where this place is not a good one to expose it. I come here to seek your kind help preferably from someone who knows what s/he's talking about or a clear final "no it's not possible that way, do it that other way, because of this" (the because being mandatory - please no peremptory answers).

Comment: Method A involves using only include(CTest) that creates lots of targets like Experimental, Nightly, etc.

Comment: Method B involves using cmake code like ctest_* commands like ctest_start, ctest_build, ctest_test, ctest_submit, etc.

Comment: I don't use ctest_* commands at all, I let the automatic behavior (the one implemented by including CTest alone) do its job (and I want it so preferably because it's out of the box).

Comment: Under windows with msvc9, the command line of Experimental build is for example:
`CommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\ctest.exe&quot; -C $(OutDir) -D Experimental&#x0D;&#x0A;if errorlevel 1 goto :VCReportError"`
It doesn't yield a subproject update in CDash, but a project update.